# Icon changing Script

Tags: bash, directory, icons, automator

i can't get this program to work with files with spaces in them.
it keeps erroring out even when i modify it for the code to have "\ " before every space

what happened was i found this code online and it works as a shell script when you send the info and the files have no spaces, now i'm trying to get it to work in automator and with any file

```
iconSource="$1"
iconDestination="$2"
newiconSource="${iconSource}"
newiconDestination="${iconDestination}"
echo $newiconSource
echo $newiconDestination
icon=/tmp/`basename $newiconSource`
rsrc=/tmp/icon.rsrc

# Create icon from the iconSource
cp $newiconSource $icon

# Add icon to image file, meaning use itself as the icon
sips -i $icon

# Take that icon and put it into a rsrc file
DeRez -only icns $icon > $rsrc

# Apply the rsrc file to
SetFile -a C $newiconDestination

if [ -f $newiconDestination ]; then
# Destination is a file
Rez -append $rsrc -o $newiconDestination
elif [ -d $newiconDestination ]; then
# Destination is a directory
# Create the magical Icon\r file
touch $newiconDestination/$'Icon\r'
Rez -append $rsrc -o $newiconDestination/Icon?
SetFile -a V $newiconDestination/Icon?
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler piece of code reproducing your problem:

```
file="hello world"
rm $file
```

This outputs:

```
rm: cannot remove `hello': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `world': No such file or directory
```

(if it doesn't, it just deleted your files named "hello" and "world". Sorry about that.)

To fix it, you have to double quote all references to variables to prevent globbing and wordsplitting:

```
file="hello world"
rm "$file"  # <- Note double quotes
```

[ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically points this out. Run your script through it, and it'll point out most of the references that need quoting.

Comment: i tried adding the qouotws and it still doesn't work

Comment: Make sure you don't have backslashes in front of your spaces in your data

Comment: i also checked that too

Comment: Yes but it was because i put the quote in the wrong spot. Thank you thank you thank you!